# Hmisc imputation

Tags: multiple-imputation

I tried to do multiple imputations with Hmisc package.
It seemed to work, but now I want to actually use the imputed values as part of my sample and run further analyses. 
Could someone please tell me where do I find the imputed values and how do I integrate them into my data frame?

Thanks!

Comment: This belongs in stackoverflow and also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Try reading the documentation for `aregImpute`. The imputed values are in `$imputed`.

Answer (score 2):

As stated before this belongs in stackoverflow, with tag `r`.  But a brief answer is to bring up the help file for `aregImpute` and look at the example that uses `impute.transcan`.  A data frame is created with one of the imputations filling in the `NA`s.